# Customizing deserialization

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, xml-deserialization

I have XML that incorporates HTML as a tag value. I do not control the XML. The deserializer sees a **p** node and it's value. However, the **div** class does not have a **p** property. The contents of this node could be ANY valid html.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Patient xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir">
  <text>
    <status value="generated"/>
    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <p>Patient Donald D DUCK @ Acme Healthcare, Inc. MR = 123456</p>
    </div>
  </text>
  ...
```

I need to catch the loading of the **div** node, and set the *value* of the **div** node to the *contents* of the div node, it this case:

```
<p>Patient Donald D DUCK @ Acme Healthcare, Inc. MR = 123456</p>
```

I would do this as a CDATA tag, but I did not create the spec. Is there a way to override the deserialization process ?

Comment: Sounds like what you need to do is process the XML as XML, rather than using that deserializer.

Comment: If the contents can be any valid HTML then the final result most likely won't be valid XML and hence you won't be able to use the standard .NET XML parser. Perhaps try http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/‎.